# I cannot invoke command while clicking on listview items Xamarin forms

Tags: forms, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I encountered problem in which, In a `List` view I can invoke the first element, and only first. I also want to trigger my command when the row `Cell` is clicked anywhere inside, but my command triggers only when the label clicked and only in the first cell. Any ideas to resolve my problem? Thanks a lot

```
<StackLayout Grid.Row="3">
  <ListView x:Name="meetingList" ItemsSource="{Binding MeetingDetails}" RowHeight = "100">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate >
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Red">
            <ContentView>
              <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                  <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                  <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                  <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackLayout  Margin="10,0" BackgroundColor="red" Padding="15,10,15,10" HeightRequest="100" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" >
                  <Label x:Name="Label_Name" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                  <Label>
                    <Label.FormattedText>
                      <FormattedString>
                        <Span Text="{Binding DateOfStart}" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                        <Span Text="-"></Span>
                        <Span Text="{Binding DateOfEnd}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                      </FormattedString>
                    </Label.FormattedText>
                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                      <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.ShowDetailsCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=calendarPage}}"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                  </Label>
                </StackLayout>
              </Grid>
            </ContentView>
            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
              <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.ShowDetailsCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=meetingList}}"></TapGestureRecognizer>
            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
          </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opvUi.png)

Comment: What is your command doing? Are they finishing? If not, you won't be able to fire another item tapped event .

Comment: FYI, the `BindingContext` of a `ListView` item is automatically set to that item. So if you add a `CommandParameter="{Binding .}"` you will get the item tapped as your command parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your layout like following code.

```
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="3">
    <ListView x:Name="meetingList" ItemsSource="{Binding MeetingDetails}" RowHeight = "100">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate >
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Red">

                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.ShowDetailsCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=meetingList}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

                        <ContentView>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <StackLayout  Margin="10,0" BackgroundColor="red" Padding="15,10,15,10" HeightRequest="100" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" >
                                    <Label x:Name="Label_Name" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                    <Label>
                                        <Label.FormattedText>
                                            <FormattedString>
                                                <Span Text="{Binding DateOfStart}" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                                <Span Text="-"></Span>
                                                <Span Text="{Binding DateOfEnd}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                            </FormattedString>
                                        </Label.FormattedText>
                                        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.ShowDetailsCommand}"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                                        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                    </Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Grid>
                        </ContentView>

                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Here is running GIF.
[image]

I do not know what is your mean about `<TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.ShowDetailsCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=calendarPage}}"></TapGestureRecognizer>`

If you want to get the click item's model. You can use `CommandParameter` like this code.`<TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.ShowDetailsCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=meetingList}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"></TapGestureRecognizer>`

In the ViewModel, you can get the click model.

```
  ShowDetailsCommand = new Command<MyModel>((key)=> {

            var myStr = key;

            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + myStr.Name+" "+myStr.DateOfStart+" "+myStr.DateOfEnd);

        });
```

Here is my demo.
https://github.com/851265601/ListviewCLickCommand

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that:

```
<StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.ShowDetailsCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=meetingList}}"></TapGestureRecognizer>
</StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
```

Captures the Tap and so the internal TapGestureRecognizer is not doing anything because the Tap is already captured.  The best way would be to use an EventToCommandBehavior

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/reusable/event-to-command-behavior

And capture the ItemSelected event.  Something along these lines

```
<ListView.Behaviors>
    <prism:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="ItemSelected"
                          Command="{Binding SymbolClickedCommand}"
                          EventArgsParameterPath="SelectedItem" />
</ListView.Behaviors>
```

The above is using Prism which provides a EventToCommandBehavior but it the same idea using the one defined in the link

I have a general rule in Xamarin, if I think I need to use TapGestureRecognizer then I am doing something wrong.  But that is probably opinion

Comment: Thank you buddy, I am working with xamarin only for 2 weeks, so I know nothing, so every opinion is important to me. I resolve problem with the labels, now the whole cell is clickable, but only first cell do you think that implementation of this EventToCommand is necessary

Comment: First off what is calendarPage?  I don't see it defined anywhere but I'll assume it is the Views name.   I am not able to test but the I believe that <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers> consumes the Tap.  The label Tap is not getting invoked.  It just seems that it is the first label, it is really the List Command that is being Invoked.  I would put a Command in the model, remove the Source on the labels Command and see if this Command ever gets called